# How to created a shared generator used by two scripts

Tags: python, module

My goal is to have two scripts that use the same generator from one of the script, that sort of looks like the not-working code below:

```
# scriptA.py 
def generator():
    num = 0
    while True:
        yield(num)
        num += 1

my_generator = generator()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # start scriptB in a thread,
    # print ouput from scriptB
    # wait until scriptB is finished
    a = 0
    while a <= 5:
        print('script A: {}'.format(my_generator.next()))
        a += 1

# scriptB.py (a separate file)

from scriptA import my_generator

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    a = 0
    while a <= 5:
        print('script B: {}'.format(my_generator.next()))
        a += 1
```

The output of above code as expected is

```
script B: 1       
script B: 2       
script B: 3       
script B: 4       
script B: 5       
script A: 1       
script A: 2       
script A: 3
script A: 4       
script A: 5
```

However, I want the output to be like

```
script B: 1       
script B: 2       
script B: 3       
script B: 4       
script B: 5       
script A: 6       
script A: 7       
script A: 8
script A: 9       
script A: 10
```

I understand that when I import `my_generator` from scriptA it creates a new `my_generator` inside the scriptB.

So my question is, is it possible to get second output without having to pass value of `my_generator.next()` from scriptA to scriptB while maintain the general structure of scriptA's '**main**'?

Also, just want to be clear, I know that this idea is probably a bad practice, but I just want to know for the sake of knowing.

Comment: State is not carried over between two scripts. You have two separate *processes* here, not just two separate modules.

Comment: Loops are endless (a is not updated at all), you have syntax error - missing colon and brackets.

Comment: @TomRon Sorry about that, it has been fixed

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a way so that state can be carried over between two scripts?

Comment: @user1948847 between two scripts? It's ambiguous. You have to decide if you want threads or processes. You talk about threads and your code doesn't attempt to spawn a secondary thread. Instead it looks like something prepared to be launched as separate processes. Anyway there are ways to share data but the approach is completely different in case of threads compared to processes.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Any way is welcomed :) Maybe process?

Answer (score 0):

Using `threading` and `join` can get you what you want.

The following code starts a thread, sets it running, then waits (`joins`) for it.  Then it continues with the main code.

Note that `threading` is low level and doesn't have that many features.  I suggest using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) if possible.  If you want to stick with standard Python libraries, use `multiprocessing`, specifically the `Pool.async` function.  For high performance stuff use Python3's `asyncio` library.

### source

```
import threading

def generator():
    num = 0
    while True:
        yield(num)
        num += 1

def scriptb(gen):
    a = 0
    while a <= 5:
        print('script B: {}'.format(gen.next()))
        a += 1

my_generator = generator()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # start scriptB in a thread,
    # print ouput from scriptB
    # wait until scriptB is finished

    t = threading.Thread(target=scriptb, args=[my_generator])
    t.start()
    t.join()

    a = 0
    while a <= 5:
        print('script A: {}'.format(my_generator.next()))
        a += 1
```

### output

```
script B: 0
script B: 1
script B: 2
script B: 3
script B: 4
script B: 5
script A: 6
script A: 7
script A: 8
script A: 9
script A: 10
script A: 11
```

Comment: Umm, maybe I have not made myself clear. scriptA and scriptB are 2 separate python file, and generator used by scriptB is imported from scriptA. I believe your code won't work in this case

Comment: since the `my_generator` object is explicitly passed in, it will.  The original code was importing a global.